# Error while adding minutes to a js date object?

Tags: javascript

```
var d=ed;
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 30);
```

`ed` has my date,but this is giving me error like

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

wat might be the problem???

Comment: I guess it isn't. What *exactly* is `ed`, is it really a `Date` instance?

Comment: This worked for me `var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()+30);` Is `ed` a `Date` object?

Comment: yeah...it is date only..resDate = new Date(ed).add(Date.MINUTE, 2); this is working,but i dont want this method,as it`s ruining my date format..

Comment: "ruining my date format" - Date instances don't really have a format; they just represent dates. Only if you're converting them to strings you'll have to define a format. Doesn't the change `d = new Date(ed)` work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var d = new Date(ed);
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 30);
```